# Toolbar Showing on load, but dissappearing

Tags: android-layout, android-toolbar

My Toolbar shows when loading, but then my mapfragment covers it and it is no longer visible.  Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@color/white_80_opacity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reduce_screen_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_exit_48dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#708090" />
```

In code I set the first toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.top_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("State College");

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move my Toolbar to the bottom of the layout file.  I assume it is like a z-index factor.  Here is my updated file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@color/white_80_opacity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reduce_screen_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_exit_48dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#708090" />
```